# Disable double click in auto generated select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Greeting, I've successfully created a select field that looks exactly like in django admin manytomany field in my html page [EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL1Nb.png). but now i want to disable on double click function from this field, I've tried dozen of method  already from previous asked question in this site and I've already disable the entire page double click function but I still able to double click, can anyone help me with this thanks, below is my code :

html :

```
 <div class="field">
    <select name="settings-user" id="id_settings-user" multiple="multiple" class="selectfilter" data-field-name="User" data-is-stacked="0">
            <option value={{ form.user }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/third_party/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/SelectBox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/SelectFilter2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#id_settings-user").dblclick(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
</script>
```

On page load :

```
<div class="selector-chosen">
    <h2>Chosen User </h2>
    <select id="id_settings-user_to" multiple="multiple" size="0" name="settings-user" class="filtered">
        <option value="1" title="Person A">Person A</option>
        <option value="2" title="Person B">Person B</option>
    </select><a href="#" id="id_settings-user_remove_all_link" class="selector-clearall active">Remove all</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with dynamically generated html tags then you should use `document` selector and `on()` method, take a look at this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("dblclick", "*", function(e) {
        console.log("Console log before disable dbclick")
        return false
        console.log("Console log after disable dbclick")
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="field">
    <select name="settings-user" id="id_settings-user" multiple="multiple" class="selectfilter" data-field-name="User" data-is-stacked="0">
            <option>Value 1</option>
            <option>Value 2</option>
            <option>Value 3</option>
            <option>Value 4</option>
            <option>Value 5</option>               
    </select>
</div>
<div class="selector-chosen">
    <h2>Chosen User </h2>
    <select id="id_settings-user_to" multiple="multiple" size="0" name="settings-user" class="filtered">
        <option value="1" title="Person A">Person A</option>
        <option value="2" title="Person B">Person B</option>
    </select><a href="#" id="id_settings-user_remove_all_link" class="selector-clearall active">Remove all</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @SilverSurfer thanks for your input, this should have work but still, the double click is still functional and on console, only "Console log before disable dbclick" is displayed

Comment: Is functional just before disable dbclick (return false). The console log is to show you how it works. You can remove console logs.

Comment: owh yes2, my bad, but I mean, the double click is still functional, I can still select deselect option by double clicking.